# Get performances metrics

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

How to get performance metrics for mapreduce applications I run in my command line such as CPU usage, network bandwidth. IO bandwidth... but in proper way that I can save the results and visualize them. Is there a web UI for that (for yarn web UI I don't get much details about the applications I run)

Comment: This doesn't exist out of the box... You would basically have to configure Prometheus exporters on your YARN nodes to get that data.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried cloudera manager ? As far as I know it does not have many metrics but it does have cluster information maybe you can extract some performace information from there.
You can find the documentation for it here:[Cloudera manager documentation](https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-14-x/topics/cloudera_manager.html)